# JPA funciton findFieldById() extends JpaRepository didn't work properly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {
    String findNameById(Integer id);

    int getClassidById(Integer id);
}
```

I used those functions for a time and they worked well before, but today all of them return an entity object instead of single property
Such as findNameById(id) returns a Student object which cause 
`ClassCastException: db.entity.Student cannot be cast to java.lang.String`
Even it can't return Map like :

```
Map<String, Object> findOneById(Integer id);
```

And My IDEA will notice `'Student' domain type or valid projection interface expected here`

```
@Query("select s.name from Student s where s.id = ?1")
String findNameById(Integer id);
```

Only do I use `@Query` that they work properly. Does anyone has this problem?
**(spring-data-jpa 2.2.5.RELEASE)**

Comment: This part of code your shared is working correctly. Show us more code

Answer (score 0):

Your JPARepository references a Student object. Which is why it returns a Student with a specific Id that you request in that method argument.

However In your Native query, you are explicitly asking for `s.name` and for that reason you are getting back a String value of that name

You can get the object and extract the name from this object, if you would like to retain your JpaRepository<Student, Integer> extension to the StudentRepository. Get an Optional returned from your JPA. Then in your service layer extract the name

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {
    Optional<Student> findById(Integer id);
}
```

And in your service class,

```
public class StudentService {
    public void processStudent(){
          Optional<Student> student = studentRepository.findById(1);
          if(student.isPresent()){
            Student studentEntity = student.get();
            String name = studentEntity.getName();
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro. Actually I just want Student's name and the function findNameById() returned name before, I don't know what's happend to it

Comment: You're welcome. You can use native query to get that. But recommended method is to move out of native query like you're doing because the more changes come in, the more difficult it is to find the bug if at all something changes unknowingly. Better to get the object and manipulate it in the service class.